# How to resize Model in react-native-dropdown-picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-dropdown-picker

I have used react-native-dropdown-picker to showed items in Modal. The problem is that the modal showing with full screen of mobile and i can't able to resize it. I tried below code but no luck.  Can anyone help to solve the issue?

[image]

Example code:

```
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';

function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {label: 'Apple', value: 'apple'},
    {label: 'Banana', value: 'banana'}
  ]);

  return (
    <DropDownPicker
      open={open}
      value={value}
      items={items}
      setOpen={setOpen}
      setValue={setValue}
      setItems={setItems}

        listMode="MODAL"   // list mode is MODAL
        modalProps={{ animationType: "fade", width: "50%", height: '50%'}}
        modalContentContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: "#fff", width:'50%', height:'50%'}}
    />
  );
}
```

Expected: The modal container should show like react-native modal popup.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set it to a fixed width you can use the style prop.

```
style={{
  width: '50%',
}}
```

I am actually trying to figure out how to remove the width altogether.  This is the third package for a dropdown that has a set width instead of allowing the container to grow normally.  This should help you though.